# How to drop an argument (from the list of arguments) in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following (MWE) shell script `foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ARGS=("$@") # all arguments
## => if it exists, we need to drop the argument "-D" here
ls -l ${ARGS[@]} | sort -fk8
```

If `foo` is called with argument `-D` (the position in the list of arguments is unknown), how can I remove `-D` from the list of arguments? I found out that `unset ARGS[${#ARGS[@]}-1]` can drop the last argument, for example, but I'm not sure in which order the arguments are passed (so I first need to know at which place the argument is and then remove it in case it is provided).

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: That's why: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36798/how-to-get-case-insensitive-sort-in-dired-new-idea and because I'm simply interested in how this can be done in shell scripts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The no-frills approach is to simply loop over the positional parameters, collecting all but `-D` into an array, and then use `set --` to update the params:

```
for param; do 
    [[ ! $param == '-D' ]] && newparams+=("$param")
done
set -- "${newparams[@]}"  # overwrites the original positional params
```

Comment: In bash, you can even do `newparams+=("$param")`.

Answer (score 7):

With `zsh`, use the `${array:#pattern}` parameter expansion operator:

```
$ set foo -D -D bar '' $'a\nb'
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${@:#-D}"
<foo>
<bar>
<>
<a
b>
```

POSIXly:

```
for i do
  [ "$i" = -D ] || set -- "$@" "$i"
  shift
done
printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
```

BTW, you forgot the quotes, `--` and `-d`:

```
ls -ld -- "$@"
```

If you want to sort by modification time, you can just use the `-t` option, here with `-r` (reverse) for oldest first:

```
ls -lrtd -- "$@"
```

Beware that if `$ARGS` is an empty array, it will list `.`. So you can do:

```
[ "$@" -eq 0 ] || ls -lrtd -- "$@"
```

To sort *reliably* based on the hour of the day irrespective of date, with `zsh` and a `ls` implementation that supports `-U` for not sorting:

```
zmodload zsh/stat # best in ~/.zshrc
bytime() zstat -LA REPLY -F%T  +mtime -- $REPLY
ls --full-time  -ldU -- .(e{'reply=("$@")'}o+bytime)
```

With limited shells like `bash`, it's very hard to sort files based on arbitrary metadata like that. Again, if you've got access to recent GNU tools, it's slightly easier:

```
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && (
  export LC_ALL=C
  printf '%s\0' "$@" |
    sed -z 's|^-$|./-|' |
    xargs -r0 stat --printf '%y\t%n\0' -- |
    sort -zk2,2 |
    cut -zf 2-
) | xargs -r0 ls -lUd --
```

Portably (but still using the non-standard `ls -U` here), it's generally easier to resort to `perl`, like:

```
perl -MPOSIX -e '
  exec qw{ls -ldU --}, 
    map {$_->[1]}
    sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]}
    map {[strftime("%T", localtime((lstat$_)[9])), $_]}
    @ARGV' -- "$@"
```